# Eclipse stops at 57% when launching Xdebug debugging session

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu, xdebug

Debugging using Eclipse and XDebug has worked fine on my workstation for a long time and suddenly it stopped. It freezes at 57% saying: "Launching: waiting for XDebug session".

I checked similar questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718933/eclipse-xdebug-freezes-at-57), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534302/waiting-for-the-xdebug-session-57-in-eclipse-pdt), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121672/eclipse-xampp-xdebug-waiting-for-xdebug-session-stays-in-57), [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/166969/), [here](http://www.agilepman.com/2010/09/launching-waiting-for-xdebug-session/), [here](http://www.b2hq.com/blog/waiting-xdebug-session-problem-eclipsexdebug-remote-debug) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/438057/cant-start-xdebug).

I have a following configuration:

**Host:** Ubuntu 14.10, Eclipse Luna

**Server:** CentOS 6.5 with PHP 5.6.6 and Apache 2.2.15 running as VM on VitualBox in network bridge mode

*XDebug settings in Eclipse*

[image: XDebug settings in Eclipse]

*XDebug server configuration (/etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini):*

```
; Enable xdebug extension module
zend_extension=xdebug.so

; see http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_mode = req
;xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.100.4
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart = Off
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log

xdebug.profiler_enable = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /media/sf_proofhq/web2/log/profiler
xdebug.profiler_output_name = %s%R.cachegrind
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

I have tried the following:

- disable remote_connect_back and enable remote_host
- upgrade PHP (from 5.5.4 to 5.6.6)
- change port from 9000 to 9001 or 9900
- restart host, VM/server and Eclipse
- [check XDebug logs](http://pastebin.com/1fch1wTX)
- switch VM network settings to NAT & Host only

Nothing has helped. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround: create a new Virtual Host and new Eclipse Workspace.

UPDATE:

If Eclipse keeps breaking at first line, then do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324156/prevent-xdebug-to-break-at-first-line-of-index-file).